# Atom's application window disappeared

Tags: applications, window-manager

I have been using Atom for many months on Macbook (now 10.15.7), but in the past week or so, its window has started disappearing more and more often.

If I right-click on a file, and then *Open in* -> *Atom*, or click the Atom icon, I do not see the application window.  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> shows Atom, but choosing Atom does not show the application window.

The  Atom menu does appear at the top of my monitor (see screenshot), but with relevant options disabled: For example, the *File* menu does not show any open files, nor the option of  opening a file.

I have two external monitors, and sometimes an application will be off-monitor except a small fraction of the application window, but I cannot find such a fractional window.

I tried uninstall/reinstall; I tried unplugging external monitors; I also tried  various Hide/Show options in the Atom dock right-click menu and the main Atom menu; but am still not seeing it.

How can I show Atom?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem right now. I then found the Atom windows reduced to a pixel-thin line at the bottom left of the screen. I could expand them from there.