# Atom app on Mac does not show open windows

Tags: applications, catalina

Atom keeps getting stuck in the background somewhere.

I can't view any of the open tabs or windows. Bring All To Front option doesn't work.

Sometimes I can bring up Mission Control and see the window hiding amongst all my other apps and clicking that works.

Sometimes it doesn't show up anywhere at all and opening new documents just brings the app to the front but no windows are visible.

[Some have suggested](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406539/128255) it sometimes does this strange thing of collapsing to a thin line but this doesn't happen in my case.

I completely deleted it and replaced it with latest version 1.54.0 but that didn't fix it.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

When you open Atom or a file by right clicking Atom icon, you may not see your atom window but you will be able to see the top bar like below

[image]

Now Select "Tile Window to the left of the screen" and click on another file and select "Tile Window to the right of the screen".

Once you see both the screens you should be able to minimize/ maximize or close and reopen. When you restart you should be able to see the full Atom Window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its happening in Atom.

In my case it hid in the left corner as a thin line. I put cursor around and found out then resize.

I also tried split screen where hidden windows will show, but it does not work all the time if it hides as thin line window.